# Find and replace "$$" with regex.replace

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, replace, escaping

I have some code that uses double dollar signs to signify comment lines. I need to add some text prior to some of those comment lines. My goal is to search for those comments like "$$ Comment" and to replace with something like this, "Prior line" & vbNewLine & "$$ Comment". I am able to find it by escaping my search term "$$ Comment" with Regex.Escape() which modifies it to this; "\$\$\ Comment". But the replacement string that is produced when I pass this escaped string to Regex.Replace() is, due to the nature of the method, a single dollar; "$ Comment". Is there a work-around to the way that "$$" is always replaced as "$" when using Regex.Replace or String.Replace?

Comment: what language is this (other than regex)?

Comment: Please tag your question with the language (VB.Net?) and show the code you tried to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the substitution string, you escape the dollar sign with another dollar sign: `"$$$$ Comment"`. [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#substitutions)

Alternatively, you can capture the comment in a group `(\$\$ Comment)` and use a group reference in the substitution string to restore it: `"$1"`

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!

Dim myRegex As New Regex(escapedSearchRegex)
Dim Result As String = myRegex.Replace(RichTextBox3.Text, ReplaceText)

'fix the double dollar replacements
Dim pattern As String = "^\$\ "
Dim replacement As String = "$$$ "
Dim Result2 As String = Regex.Replace(Result, pattern, replacement,RegexOptions.Multiline)